# How to wait for constructor to finish?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class constructor that has async elements. Later when I create an instance of this class, I want to read a property that will only exist when the constructor finished 100%. I always run into problem `Can not read property 'id' of undefined.` I'm almost sure this is a problem about async .. await.

```
    class NewPiecePlease {
        constructor(IPFS, OrbitDB) { 
            this.OrbitDB = OrbitDB;
    
            (async () => {
                this.node = await IPFS.create();
        
                // Initalizing OrbitDB
                this._init.bind(this);
                this._init();
            })();
        }
    
        // This will create OrbitDB instance, and orbitdb folder.
        async _init() {
            this.orbitdb = await this.OrbitDB.createInstance(this.node);
            console.log("OrbitDB instance created!");
    
            this.defaultOptions = { accessController: { write: [this.orbitdb.identity.publicKey] }}
    
            const docStoreOptions = {
                ...this.defaultOptions,
                indexBy: 'hash',
            }
            this.piecesDb = await this.orbitdb.docstore('pieces', docStoreOptions);
            await this.piecesDb.load();
        }
        ...
   }
```

Later I create an instance of this class like this:

```
(async () => {
    const NPP = new NewPiecePlease;
    console.log(NPP.piecesDb.id);
    // This will give 'undefined' error
})();
```

How can I tell NodeJS that I want `new NewPiecePlease` to fully finish? `await console.log(NPP.piecesDb.id);` does not help, which is understandable, because it won't understand what I'm await-ing. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: remove the iife, then use a getter for props which you await on i.e `await NPP.piecesDb.load()`, `new NewPiecePlease` and its props cant be synchronous

Comment: also why are you bind'ing this?

Comment: I created a getter like this 
`get piecesDb() {
        return this.piecesDb;
    }` but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: I rewrote this from a documentation. The API changed. Originally it was like this: `this.node.on("ready", this._init.bind(this))` But those events doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory for this. They are very good for doing complex, potentially async object creation and to keep your constructors clean and focused.

```
 class NewPiecePlease {
  constructor(orbitdb, node, pieceDB) {
    this.orbitdb = orbitdb;
    this.node = node;
    this.pieceDB = pieceDB;
  }
  
  static async create(IPFS, OrbitDB) {
    const node = await IPFS.create();
    const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(node);
    console.log("OrbitDB instance created!");

    const defaultOptions = {
      accessController: {
        write: [orbitdb.identity.publicKey]
      }
    }

    const docStoreOptions = { ...defaultOptions, indexBy: 'hash' };
    const piecesDb = await orbitdb.docstore('pieces', docStoreOptions);
    
    await piecesDb.load();
    
    return new NewPiecePlease(orbitdb, node, piecedb);
  }
}
```

As you can see the create method does all the async stuff and just passes the results into the constructor where it really doesn't have to do anything except assign and maybe validate some arguments.

```
(async () => {
    const NPP = await NewPiecePlease.create(IPFS, OrbitDB);
    console.log(NPP.piecesDb.id);
    // This will give 'undefined' error
})();
```

Comment: do I need to call create?